# Verify guest order and set guest order state

Tags: checkout, customer, email, order-status

I'm trying to implement an order confirmation module for guest accounts. I researched now for a couple hours but it seems that I can't find any solution to my problem.

I need to verify if the email of a guest customer is actually valid. After the order is placed I observe the `sales_order_place_after` event and try to set the guest order to `holded` or a custom one like `unconfirmed`. Either way the `state` change gets overwritten by Magento.
After that I want to send an email with a verification link. And then change the `state` back to `pending`. I think I can overwrite the basic email template for a new guest order. Is this correct?

How can I set guest orders to a different state than the default "pending"?

Thank you all very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just observe the `sales_order_save_before` event, find a correct condition (this is important) how to determine, you change the status for the correct orders (not every time, an order is saved) and set the status

Comment: Hmm. I have the correct order but the state still gets overwritten.

I have something like this:

`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($observer->event->order["increment_id"]);

$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED, true);

$order->save();`

Comment: you need to get the order from the observer `$observer->getOrder()->setState()`

Comment: `$observer->getOrder()->setState()` gives me back the correct order of the observer instance. I can now change the state of the current order. But it only works if I observer the `sales_order_place_after` event.

Comment: It should work in `sales_order_save_before` also. The problem is, that the status is changed after `sales_order_place_after ` but should be changed before  `sales_order_save_before`

Comment: I can set the status in both events. Say I set it to `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED`. If I set in the event `sales_order_save_before` it changes but after the order is processed it's changed back to `pending`. In `sales_order_place_after` it's the exact opposite. Either way there will be two state changes. Is it event possible to just have on state set? But just in one case. I know that you can change the default status of a state. But I need this feature only for guest orders.